# Renderer size in xtk

Tags: javascript, visualization, webgl, xtk

Playing with xtk (http://www.goxtk.org). How do you impose a size to the renderer? I'm asking because upon calling init on the renderer, the container div grows. I'm not using width or high 100% as in the examples, I'm using an absolute size. Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

It should work to specify the renderer size in pixel by adjusting the -tag which is the container for the X.renderer.

For example, this is from XTK Lesson 7 where three X.renderers are used with an absolute size (see http://lessons.goxtk.com/07/):

```
...
<div id='r1' style='background-color:#000000; float: left; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin:10px;'></div>
<div id='r2' style='background-color:#000000; float: left; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin:10px;'></div>
<div id='r3' style='background-color:#000000; float: left; width: 300px; height: 300px; margin:10px;'></div>
...
```

Nevertheless, for the automatic progressbar to be displayed properly, the  position style is changed to *relative*. This might cause the container to adjust depending on how your general page layout looks.

If you rather want the *absolute* position style and don't need the progressbar, you can disable it like this which also prevents changing the position style of the  container:

```
...
r1 = new X.renderer('r1');
r1.config.PROGRESSBAR_ENABLED = false;
r1.init();
...
```